# Singular name Plugin localization

Tags: plugin-development, localization, l10n

I'm trying to localize the singular name of a custom post type.

```
...
'singular_name' => __('key', 'plugindomain')
...
```

I created a .po and compiled it as .mo. I also loaded the translation using `load_plugin_textdomain` using the `init` action.

```
// $directory plugin directory relative to plugins dir
load_plugin_textdomain('plugindomain', false, $directory);
```

The string *are* localized correctly in the backend sidebar. However, the strings are not translated in the frontend with:

```
// $post_type returned from get_post_type_object
echo $post_type->labels->singular_name;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

Apparently the problem is related to [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/). Strings are loaded before the multilanguage plugin mentioned sets the current language during the execution. Is there a way to trigger the registration of post types after the language changes made by Polylang have had their effect?